# TO_DATE EN ORACLE

Tags: c#, oracle

Recibo mi dato fecha en este formato `2/27/2020.

Mi insert esta de esta manera:

```
INSERT INTO XXXX.XXXXX(XXX,FECHA) VALUES (:XXXX, TO_DATE(:FECHA, MMDDYYYY));
```

Depende la fecha que se recibe quisiera que saliera de esta manera.

```
 Julio 9, 2020
```

Sin embargo recibo esta exception:

> {"ORA-00984: column not allowed here"}

Pero si lo quito me marca esto:

> not a valid month ora-01843

Como  puedo obtener ese resultado?

Comment: En principio, lo que veo, es que te faltan  comillas en el formato: `'MMDDYYYY'`

Comment: Ya le añadi las comillas. El dato que se debe convertir viene de un array int, y ahora recibo este msj ' a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected' y no esta conviertiendolo de igual manera